# Oracle APEX (build 22.2.1) - Issue with passing large IDs (39 digits) stored in page item using Branch Link

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a hierarchical tree and originally using the following sql:

```
select 
case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
    when level = 1             then 1
else                           -1
    end as status, 
level, 
C."Name" || ' (' || C."Alias" || ')' as title, 
null as icon, 
C.ID as value, 
null as tooltip, 
f?p=&APP_ID.:1105:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P1105_ID:'||"ID" as link 
from VBORGUNT C
WHERE C.ID_STNT = 190925678486461946459250188392520804336
start with C.ID_BORGUNT = 0
connect by prior C.ID = C.ID_BORGUNT
order siblings by C.”Name”`
```

The link works correctly opening a model page to the specific tree node record selected.
I moved the sql code to a View except for the link.  Using the View I populated the tree attributes; however, the ‘Selected Node Page Item’ does not populate the page item P1124_NODE_ID when a node is clicked.

Therefore, in the Tree Attribute Link field I configured a URL as  "javascript:apex.item("P1124_NODE_ID").setValue(&ID.)", and now when I click on a tree node the P1124_NODE_ID page item is populated with the node id.
I assigned a Dynamic Action to the page item P1124_NODE_ID to submit the page whenever the value of P1124_NODE_ID changes.

When the Submit Page is executed, I have an ‘After Processing’ Branch that links to page P1105.

Here's the problem:

Everything works correctly as long as the ID being passed is a small number such as 11111; however, if the ID is much larger such as most of the IDs that are 39 digits long then the Model page displays an error message stating record is not found.
Please note, this is not a problem for other pages.

For example, I have the same data on another page that is rendered in an Interactive Grid.  The same records with the larger 39 digit IDs have no problem rendering the same model page P1105, so the larger numbers work in that case.

Does anyone have any idea why a Branch link will not pass the larger ID numbers to a Modal page but will when linking from an Interactive Grid?

Appreciate any help!!!

Included in overall question.

Comment: One followup: Concerning the page item P1124_NODE_ID that stores the node id, I've tried numerous field types (e.g., Number, Text Field, Textarea) and in all cases the larger numbers display in scientific notation format such as 2.199320054402639e+38

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved!

On the Oracle Apex forum, users fac586 and dbliss-Oracle noted that I was passing the ID as a number vs text.  By quoting $ID the large ID numbers now pass correctly:

Corrected code:
javascript:apex.item('P1124_NODE_ID').setValue('&ID.')